# How to one HTML file and different js file for different screen in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery mobile. I make two and three screen but I implement the all functionality on index.html. It is too confusing. I googled it and find that you can also make different JS file per screen (with include). But when I do like that, it doesn’t work. I don't understand why it is not working. It is too confusing  if project is big to do the coding in same page. I need that to make all HTML in one screen(index.html) and JS different for differnt screen. Here is my code .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
        <title></title>
        <!--link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css"-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.theme-1.3.1.css">
    <ink rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.theme-1.3.1.min.css">
        <!-- Extra Codiqa features -->
        <!-- jQuery and jQuery Mobile -->
        <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
        <!--script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script-->
        <!--script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script-->
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js"></script>
          <script src="js/index.js"></script>

        <!-- Extra Codiqa features -->

    </head>
    <style>

        #Home{

            background : transparent
                url(img/Background-Screen.png)
                no-repeat fixed left bottom;
            -webkit-background-size :100% 100%;
            -moz-background-size :100% 100%;
            -o-background-size :100% 100%;

            background-size : cover;
        }

        #DocumentScreen{

            background : transparent
                url(img/Background-Screen.png)
                no-repeat fixed left bottom;
            -webkit-background-size :100% 100%;
            -moz-background-size :100% 100%;
            -o-background-size :100% 100%;

            background-size : cover;
        }
        #CaseInformationScreen {

            background : transparent
                url(img/Background-Screen.png)
                no-repeat fixed left bottom;
            -webkit-background-size :100% 100%;
            -moz-background-size :100% 100%;
            -o-background-size :100% 100%;
            background-size : cover;
        }


        #UserSettingScreen {

            background : transparent
                url(img/Background-Screen.png)
                no-repeat fixed left bottom;
            -webkit-background-size :100% 100%;
            -moz-background-size :100% 100%;
            -o-background-size :100% 100%;
            background-size : cover;
        }


    </style>

    <body>
        <!--page one My Cases Screen------------->
        <div data-role="page" id="Home" > 
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" >
                <h1 class="ui-title"  id="hdr" style="text-align:left;margin-left: 100px;">My Cases</h1>
                <div class="ui-btn-right" id="headerButtons" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                    <a href="#UserSettingScreen" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="gear" data-theme="b" id="Setting" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window">Setting</a>
                    <a href="#CaseInformationScreen" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true" data-icon="plus" data-theme="b" data-rel="popup" id="Add" data-position-to="window">Add</a>
                    <a href="#newevent1" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" data-rel="dialog"id="Edit">Edit</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">

                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="folderData" >
                </ul>
                 <!--   Case Information Pop up-------------------------->
                <div data-role="popup" id="CaseInformationScreen" data-close-btn="none" style="max-width:600px !important; width: 600px !important" data-overlay-theme="a" data-dismissible="false">
                    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" >

                        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false" id="Cancel">Cancel</a>
                        <h1>Case Information</h1>
                        <a href="#" ddata-role="button" data-corners="false" id="AddButton">Add</a>
                    </div>

                     <div data-role="content">
                    <div><img src="img/Documents.png"/></div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="text-12" style="text-align:top;margin-left: 0px;">Case Name:</label>
                        <input name="text-12" id="caseNameValue" value="" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="text-12" style="text-align:left;margin-left: 0px;">Case Date:</label>
                        <input name="text-12" id="caseDate" value="" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="textarea-12">Textarea:</label>
                        <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="textarea-12" id="caseTextArea"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              <!--   Case Information Pop up End-------------------------->

                  <!--   User setting Pop up-------------------------->
              <div data-role="popup" id="UserSettingScreen" data-close-btn="none" style="max-width:300px !important; width: 300px !important" data-overlay-theme="a" data-dismissible="false">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" >
                <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false" id="CancelSettingButton">Cancel</a>
                <h1>User Settings</h1>
                <a href="#" ddata-role="button" data-corners="false">Ok</a>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">
                 <div><img src="img/Documents.png"/></div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="text-12" style="text-align:top;margin-left: 0px;">IP Address:</label>
                    <input name="text-12" id="text-12" value="" type="text"/>
                </div>  
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="text-12" style="text-align:left;margin-left: 0px;">Display Font:</label>
                    <select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1">
                        <option value="standard">A</option>
                        <option value="rush">B</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>                
        </div>
             <!--   User setting Pop up End-------------------------->

            </div>

            <script>

                        $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#Home', function() {

                       });

               </script>
        </div>

        <!--  Document Information Pop up-------------------------->  
        <div data-role="page" >
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">
                <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false">Cancel</a>
                <h1>Document Information</h1>
                <a href="#" ddata-role="button" data-corners="false">Ok</a>
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="text-12" style="text-align:top;margin-left: 0px;">Name:</label>
                <input name="text-12" id="text-12" value="" type="text">
            </div>  
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="text-12" style="text-align:left;margin-left: 0px;">Date:</label>
                <input name="text-12" id="text-12" value="" type="text">
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="textarea-12">Notes:</label>
                <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="textarea-12" id="textarea-12"></textarea>
            </div>

        </div>
      <!--  Document Information Pop up End-------------------------->   

        <!-----------Document screen------------------->
        <div data-role="page" id="DocumentScreen" > 
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" >
                <a href="#Home" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" style="text-align:left;margin-left: 20px; margin-bottom: 10px;" >Back</a>
                <h1 class="ui-title"  id="hdr" style="text-align:left;margin-left: 100px;">My Documents</h1>
                <div class="ui-btn-right" id="addbuttons" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                    <div><img src="img/Connect-Realtime.png" id="realTimeImaage"/></div>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">

                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="folderInside_Data" >
                </ul>

            </div>

            <script>


                $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#DocumentScreen', function() {
                console.log("init");
                 loadFolderContent();
                });
                        function loadFolderContent() {

                        for (i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
                        $('#folderInside_Data').append(
                          '<li class="rowID" id="' + i + '">' + '<a href="#">' + '<img src="img/Blue-Folder.png">' + '<h2>Broken Bells</h2>' + '<p>Broken Bells</p>' + '<span class="ui-li-count">' + i + '</span></a>' + '</li>'
                                );
                        }
                        $('#folderInside_Data').listview('refresh');
                        }


                $(document).on('click', '.rowID', function() {
                $.mobile.changePage($("#realTimeScreen"), {
                transition: "pop",
                        reverse: false,
                        changeHash: false
                });
                    console.log(this.id)
                });</script>
        </div>
       <!-----------Document screen End------------------->

        <!-----------------------Real Time screen----------------------------->

        <div data-role="page" id="realTimeScreen" > 
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
                <a href="#DocumentScreen" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" style="text-align:left;margin-left: 20px; margin-bottom: 10px;">Back</a>
                <h1 class="ui-title"  id="" style="text-align:left;margin-left: 100px;">Document name</h1>
                <div class="ui-btn-right" id="addbuttons" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                    <a><img src="img/Follow-Realtime.png" id=""/></a>
                    <a><img src="img/Stop-Realtime.png" id=""/></a>
                    <a><img src="img/Email-Document.png" id=""/></a>
                    <a><img src="img/Connect-Realtime.png" id=""/></a>
                    <a><img src="img/Manage-Case-Folders.png" id=""/></a>
                    <a><img src="img/Export-Realtime.png" id=""/></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content" data-theme="d">
                <div id="realTimeContents"></div>
            </div>
            <script>
         <!-----------------------add data Time screen----------------------------->
                for (i = 0; i < 400; i++) {
                $('#realTimeContents').append(
                        '<span style="margin-left:5%;">' + 12.01 + '</span><span style="margin-left: 10%;">' + 'A' + '</span><span style="margin-left: 20%;">' + 'I was deputy canine devision' + '</span>' + '<br>'+ '<br>'+ '<br>'
                        );
                }


            </script>

        </div>

</body>
<script>

                <!--<-------------------Pop Up Functionality----------------------------------------->-->
                      $(document).on('popupafteropen', '[data-role="popup"]', function(event, ui) {
                      $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
                      }).on('popupafterclose', '[data-role="popup"]', function(event, ui) {
                     $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
                      });

                 <!--<-------------------Pop Up Functionality End----------------------------------------->-->


                  <!--<-------------------Ready  Functionality----------------------------------------->-->
                     $(document).ready(function() {

                     $.mobile.loading('hide');
                     onDeviceReady();
                     });

                <!--<-------------------Ready  Functionality End----------------------------------------->-->






    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    var db = "";
     //will create database Dummy_DB or open it

    //function will be called when device ready
    function onDeviceReady(){
         db = window.openDatabase("Casepad", "1.0", "Casepad", 200000);
         if(window.localStorage.getItem("isAddSomeData")=="yes"){
          alert("Yes");   
         db.transaction(queryDB,errorCB);
          }
       //   db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
    }
    function insertData(){
    db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
    }

    //create table and insert some record
    function populateDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CaseTable (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, CaseName TEXT NOT NULL,CaseDate INTEGER ,TextArea TEXT NOT NULL)');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO CaseTable(CaseName,CaseDate,TextArea) VALUES ("'+$('#caseNameValue').val()+'", "'+$('#caseDate').val()+'","'+$('#caseTextArea').val()+'")');
    }

    //function will be called when an error occurred
    function errorCB(err) {
        alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
    }

    //function will be called when process succeed
    function successCB() {
        console.log("success!");
        db.transaction(queryDB,errorCB);
    }

    //select all from SoccerPlayer
    function queryDB(tx){
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM CaseTable',[],querySuccess,errorCB);
    }

    function querySuccess(tx,result){
     var len = result.rows.length;
      $('#folderData').empty();
      for (var i=0; i<len; i++){

              $('#folderData').append(
               '<li class="caseRowClick" id="' + i + '">' + '<a href="#">' + '<img src="img/Blue-Folder.png">' + '<h2>'+result.rows.item(i).CaseName+'</h2>' + '<p>'+result.rows.item(i).CaseDate+'</p>' + '<p>'+result.rows.item(i).TextArea+'</p>'+'<span class="ui-li-count">'+ i+'</span></a>' + '</li>'
            );
        } 
        $('#folderData').listview('refresh');

    }
    </script>
</html>

<----------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
index.js

    /**
     * QUnit v1.9.0 - A JavaScript Unit Testing Framework
     *
     * http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit
     *
     * Copyright (c) 2012 John Resig, Jörn Zaefferer
     * Dual licensed under the MIT (MIT-LICENSE.txt)
     * or GPL (GPL-LICENSE.txt) licenses.
     */

    $(document).bind('pagecreate', function(e) {
        if (e.target.id == 'Home') {
            $("#headerButtons").on("click", "a", function() {

                if ($(this).attr("id") == "Add") {
                    $('#caseNameValue').val('');
                    $('#caseDate').val('');
                    $('#caseTextArea').val('');
                } else if ($(this).attr("id") == "Setting") {
                } else if ($(this).attr("id") == "Edit") {
                }
            });

        }


        $(document).on('click', '.caseRowClick', function() {
            $.mobile.changePage($("#DocumentScreen"), {
                transition: "slide",
                reverse: false,
                changeHash: false
            });
            console.log(this.id)
        });


        $("#AddButton").click(function() {
            var isvalid = validationField();
            if (isvalid) {
                insertData();
                window.localStorage.setItem("isAddSomeData", "yes");
                $.mobile.changePage($("#Home"), {
                    transition: "slide",
                    reverse: false,
                    changeHash: false
                });
            }
        });


        $("#Cancel").click(function() {
            $('.ui-dialog').dialog('close')
            $.mobile.changePage($("#Home"), {
                transition: "pop",
                reverse: false,
                changeHash: false
            });
        });


        $("#CancelSettingButton").click(function() {
            $.mobile.changePage($("#Home"), {
                transition: "slide",
                reverse: false,
                changeHash: false
            });
        });

    });

    function validationField() {
        if ($('#caseNameValue').val() == '') {
            alert("Please Enter the Case Name");
            return false;
        } else if ($('#caseDate').val() == '') {
            alert("Please Enter the Case Date");
            return false;
        } else if ($('#caseTextArea').val() == '') {
            alert("Please Enter the Case Text Area");
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to have different js files for different pages. If you are using jquery mobile and you have one html then the different are divs with data-role="page" attribute. 
If you read the documentation of jquery mobile it says what to do for this occusion.
Check [here for the structure of the pages](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/pages/) and check [here for the events on the pages](http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/). Pay special attention on the pageinit, pagecreate, pageshow events. Those are the fundamental ones.

Comment: you can't understand my question.Actually my question is that if i add all html on index.html (it fine).But i need to add click events like button click list row click event in another js .so that i remove confusion.

Comment: It is too confusing if i have 10 screen.i also studied that we can add  our js file where we can write  events ..

Comment: It's not that confusing. Just think of it this way.. you treat every data-role="page" like a different html file, and you assign events to every page's elements in specific regions of your js. You just have to be careful to not have elements with the same id and the events that you assign depending on a class or tag selector. Just begin coding and you'll get the hang of it. If you face problems StackOverflow is not leaving, you can always come back for more questions.

Comment: Well where is the problem in that? You can have multiple js files, just include them in the right order

Comment: i changed some code .Please check it is working ..? is it ok?

Comment: Why are asking me if it's working? Can't you check it yourself?

Comment: Actually it is working .i am just asking it is good way to do things.?

Comment: First of all remove all js from html and put it in a separate file. Css too. Don't use bind, but on().

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32003/discussion-between-user2484319-and-alkis)